# Compile Linux kernel for ARM-EABI but with 4-byte large type alignment?

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, arm, eabi

By default, any large type (larger than 4 bytes) will be aligned to 8 bytes on EABI. This means that if `function(u32, u64)` is called, u32 goes into `r0`, and u64 is split between `r2` and `r3`, leaving `r1` unused.

How can I make the compiler align it on 4-bytes instead? I understand the consequences of this (breaking the ABI) or whatever, but I do not really care. Don't suggest using OABI either as enabling OABI in the kernel configuration disables the support for ARMv7.

With 4-byte alignment, u32 will still go in `r0` but the u64 will now be split between `r1` and `r2`.

Comment: I have not the slightest idea, but why do you want this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect the correct way to do this would be to recompile the toolchain with a modified definition of EABI, which you might partially crib from the the OABI you don't want to use.

You may have to re-write some of assembly language parts of the kernel too, so it might be better if you gave your modified ABI a new name.

Do expect to spend quite a bit of time understanding and fixing various things it breaks.

Comment: I was checking out the inner workings of GCC for ARM and I found this flag in the machine definitions: `ARM_DOUBLEWORD_ALIGN`. Do you changing it to `0` for EABI will make it align on 4-byte boundaries? I don't think this is going to break anything in the kernel as there are no kernel parts written in asm that depend on the alignment of large types, as long as the rest of the ABI conventions are followed.

Comment: Sounds plausible, do a recursive grep of the tree for that to figure out what it does.  Also see if the OABI definition does that, or otherwise understand what difference accomplishes the different alignment you seemed to hint that had.

Answer (score 0):

GCC has the `aligned` attribute, that can be applied to types:

```
typedef long __attribute__((aligned(4))) unaligned_long;
```

Now you can use this type when you want to (carefully).

Comment: Can I force GCC to do that for long and any type derived from it? I need to apply it to the entire kernel (ie. this will actually break the ABI for anything that calls the kernel).

Comment: I believe this just changes the alignment of specific variables; calling convention is unchanged.

Comment: @ephemient: So will that change how the args are split in the registers? If so, that does change the conventions.

Comment: I expect you'll only see changes in how things are laid out in memory, and no changes to how things are loaded into registers.

Comment: @epheminet, This will only change variables defined `unaligned_long`, not those defined `long`. It won't change parameter passing conventions in any way. If you use `-mregparm`, registers will be used, regardless of these.

Comment: @ugoren, but that's not what the question is asking :(